# Javascript - Image change an resize to full background

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a quick explanation, I created an image that resizes to fill the background using this function which works great:

```
function resize_bg(element_id){

    $("#"+element_id).css("left","0");
    var doc_width = $(window).width();
    var doc_height = $(window).height();
    var image_width = $("#"+element_id).width();
    var image_height = $("#"+element_id).height();
    var image_ratio = image_width/image_height;      
    var new_width = doc_width;
    var new_height = Math.round(new_width/image_ratio);
    if(new_height<doc_height){
        new_height = doc_height;
        new_width = Math.round(new_height*image_ratio);
        var width_offset = Math.round((new_width-doc_width)/2);
        $("#"+element_id).css("left","-"+width_offset+"px");
    }
    $("#"+element_id).width(new_width);
    $("#"+element_id).height(new_height);

    return true;
}
```

So no problem for the full background image.  The problem appears, when I change the image source using Javascript.  In other words, I have 1 image set as background but on hover of certain elements on the page, the image changes but it doesn't change the resize right.  So the first image on load is resized and positioned correctly, but when I switch the image using .attr('src',newimg) the image is not resized correctly even though I call the function again.

Here is the code I use to change the image and resize it:

```
$('#menu_work li a').hover(function(){
    $('#content').hide();
    var img_src = $(this).next('img').attr('src');
    $('#full_screen_img').attr('src', img_src );
    resize_bg();
    $('#full_screen_img').show();
},function(){
    $('#full_screen_img').hide();
    $('#content').show();
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the `resize_bg` function? Both on load and on elements hover.

Comment: @micha - Yes I have, please see the added code in the question.

Comment: Did you verify that the value of `img_src` is the value that you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@maxedison is right, you forgot to pass the element id.

Another problem is that when you change the src, the new image might not be loaded yet, so you won't get the right dimensions in `resize_bg` until it is.

In that case you'll need to resize the image once it's loaded:

```
$('#full_screen_img').attr('src', img_src ).load(function() {
    resize_bg('<ELEMENT_ID>');
});
resize_bg('<ELEMENT_ID>');
```

---

On another note, I'd recommend you change `resize_bg` to get a jQuery object instead of an `id`, or even write a plugin (`$.fn.resize_bg`) if it's a functionality you want to use often.

Comment: @maxedison is right, and you extended to forecast a problem that then occured, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by this? "change resize_bg to get a jQuery object instead of an id, or even write a plugin ($.fn.resize_bg)"

Comment: the current function expects an element id, which is quite a rigid requirement. Why not align it with jQuery? Rewrite it to accept a jQuery object, and loop over its elements, or go one step further by changing it to a jQuery plugin `$.fn.resize_bg = function() {...}`. Then you can call it by `$('...').resize_bg()` (the object gets passed via `this`)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have left out the `element_id` argument when calling `resize_bg()` in the `hover` event handler. As a result, `resize_bg()` can't find the element you want to resize.